Confused About Middleware in Node.js Express
I'm learning Express.js and I'm a bit confused about the difference between middleware functions and route handlers. I understand that middleware functions usually have the next argument, but I'm not clear on when a function is considered middleware and when it is a route handler.
Are Route Handlers Considered Middleware in Node.js Express?
Questions:

Does the following code have middlewares? And which are the middlewares in this code?
Are the functions like app.get('/', ...), app.post('/verify', ...), app.get('/home', ...), and     app.get('/logout', ...) considered middlewares?
Do middleware functions always need to have the next argument?
Can you explain the role of middleware versus route handlers in Express.js?

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const hbs = require('hbs');
const nocache = require('nocache');
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(session({
secret: 'keyboard cat',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
}));

app.use(nocache());

const username = 'admin';
const password = 'admin@123';

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
if (req.session.user) {
res.render('home');
} else {
if (req.session.passwordwrong) {
res.render('login', { msg: "invalid credentials" });
req.session.passwordwrong = false;
} else {
res.render('login');
}
}
});

app.post('/verify', (req, res) => {
if (req.body.username === username && req.body.password === password) {
req.session.user = req.body.username;
res.redirect('/home');
} else {
req.session.passwordwrong = true;
res.redirect('/');
}
});

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
if (req.session.user) {
res.render('home', { username: username });
} else {
if (req.session.passwordwrong) {
req.session.passwordwrong = false;
res.render('login', { msg: "invalid credentials" });
} else {
res.render('login');
}
}
});

app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
req.session.destroy();
res.render('login', { msg: 'logged out' });
});`your text`

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server running on port 3000'));



Like you are saying that app.get(), app.post() are route handlers that has a specific function on their own.
The middleware function are the function that working when the route is called by the route handlers.
like,
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.user) {
         res.render('home');
    } else {
         if (req.session.passwordwrong) {
              res.render('login', { msg: "invalid credentials" });
              req.session.passwordwrong = false;
         } else {
              res.render('login');
         }
    }
});

for Your questions:-

Yes, there have middlewares.
No, they are the handleres that control when or for which route the middleware function has to work.
No, if there has any other middleware for same routes then we have to give next() to finish the current middleware and jump to the next middleware.
The MIDDLEWARE functions will start to work when a route is called. But, the assignment of which middleware want to work on which route is decalred by the route handlers(app.get(), app.post(), et...).

